# Salesforce integration with APIM

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

Instead of using the Azure developer portal we are using Salesforce Experience cloud to integrate with Azure APIM. We have set up Azure AD as the identity provider in Salesforce and SSO for Salesforce with Azure AD as identity provider works fine. However we are not able to have a seemless integration with APIM from Salesforce and need assistance on what configurations with respect to tokens etc need to be explicitly passed from Salesforce in order to talk to APIM. With the ID token derived from Salesforce after the successful Azure Active Directory authentication / authorization we are unable to make successful restful callouts to APIM identity from Salesforce. We have looked at https://lekkimworld.com/2019/11/18/using-an-auth-provider-and-named-credentials-in-salesforce-with-azure-oauth/ however would really appreciate pointers on how to do a seamless single sign on from Salesforce to APIM.
Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to expose salesforce APIs through Azure APIM ? ...and use Azure AD as the identity provider to provision JWTs ?

Comment: No it is the other way around. Trying to consume APIM from Salesforce.Azure AD is the Identity provider for SSO.

Comment: ok...What is the error that you are receiving on the salesforce end ? Is there a jwt validate policy setup in Azure APIM ..what is the error reported here when you make a call from Salesforce? What are the  other policies setup in Azure APIM  ?